# how to test a string for letters only

Tags: c++

how could I test a string against only valid characters like letters a-z?...

```
string name;

cout << "Enter your name"
cin >> name;

string letters = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm";

string::iterator it;

for(it = name.begin(); it = name.end(); it++)
{
  size_t found = letters.find(it);
}
```

Comment: If this is homework... it should be marked as such.

Comment: What's your question?  Is your code wrong, or is something missing from it?  In which case, what?

Comment: `*it`. btw also try it with a dvorak layout.

Comment: Just pointing out that with ascii text you only have to check 2 ranges per character - (c >= 0x61 && c <= 0x71). Some of these solutions don't take advantage of that fact.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

STL way:

```
struct TestFunctor
{
  bool stringIsCorrect;
  TestFunctor()
  :stringIsCorrect(true)
  {}

  void operator() (char ch)
  {
    if(stringIsCorrect && !((ch <= 'z' && ch >= 'a') || (ch <= 'Z' && ch >= 'A')))
      stringIsCorrect = false;
  }
}

TestFunctor functor;

for_each(name.begin(), name.end(), functor);

if(functor.stringIsCorrect)
  cout << "Yay";
```

Comment: how about if I wanted to include a space as part of the test parameter? how would you do it?

Comment: replace `if(stringIsCorrect && !((ch <= 'z' && ch >= 'a') || (ch <= 'Z' && ch >= 'A')))` with `if(stringIsCorrect && !((ch <= 'z' && ch >= 'a') || (ch <= 'Z' && ch >= 'A') || (ch == ' ')))`

Comment: Note that encoding as [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) has characters between `'a'`and `'z'` which are not letter.

Answer (score 63):

First, using `std::cin >> name` will fail if the user enters `John Smith` because `>>` splits input on whitespace characters. You should use `std::getline()` to get the name:

```
std::getline(std::cin, name);
```

## Here we go…

There are a number of ways to check that a string contains only alphabetic characters. The simplest is probably `s.find_first_not_of(t)`, which returns the index of the first character in `s` that is not in `t`:

```
bool contains_non_alpha
    = name.find_first_not_of("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz") != std::string::npos;
```

That rapidly becomes cumbersome, however. To also match uppercase alphabetic characters, you’d have to add 26 more characters to that string! Instead, you may want to use a combination of `find_if` from the `<algorithm>` header and `std::isalpha` from `<cctype>`:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>

struct non_alpha {
    bool operator()(char c) {
        return !std::isalpha(c);
    }
};

bool contains_non_alpha
    = std::find_if(name.begin(), name.end(), non_alpha()) != name.end();
```

`find_if` searches a range for a value that matches a predicate, in this case a functor `non_alpha` that returns whether its argument is a non-alphabetic character. If `find_if(name.begin(), name.end(), ...)` returns `name.end()`, then no match was found.

## But there’s more!

To do this as a one-liner, you can use the adaptors from the `<functional>` header:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <functional>

bool contains_non_alpha
    = std::find_if(name.begin(), name.end(),
                   std::not1(std::ptr_fun((int(*)(int))std::isalpha))) != name.end();
```

The `std::not1` produces a function object that returns the logical inverse of its input; by supplying a pointer to a function with `std::ptr_fun(...)`, we can tell `std::not1` to produce the logical inverse of `std::isalpha`. The cast `(int(*)(int))` is there to select the overload of `std::isalpha` which takes an `int` (treated as a character) and returns an `int` (treated as a Boolean).

Or, if you can use a C++11 compiler, using a lambda cleans this up a lot:

```
#include <cctype>

bool contains_non_alpha
    = std::find_if(name.begin(), name.end(),
                   [](char c) { return !std::isalpha(c); }) != name.end();
```

`[](char c) -> bool { ... }` denotes a function that accepts a character and returns a `bool`. In our case we can omit the `-> bool` return type because the function body consists of only a `return` statement. This works just the same as the previous examples, except that the function object can be specified much more succinctly.

## And (almost) finally…

In C++11 you can also use a regular expression to perform the match:

```
#include <regex>

bool contains_non_alpha
    = !std::regex_match(name, std::regex("^[A-Za-z]+$"));
```

## But of course…

None of these solutions addresses the issue of locale or character encoding! For a locale-independent version of `isalpha()`, you’d need to use the C++ header `<locale>`:

```
#include <locale>

bool isalpha(char c) {
    std::locale locale; // Default locale.
    return std::use_facet<std::ctype<char> >(locale).is(std::ctype<char>::alpha, c);
}
```

Ideally we would use `char32_t`, but `ctype` doesn’t seem to be able to classify it, so we’re stuck with `char`. Lucky for us we can dance around the issue of locale entirely, because you’re probably only interested in English letters. There’s a handy header-only library called [UTF8-CPP](http://utfcpp.sourceforge.net/) that will let us do what we need to do in a more encoding-safe way. First we define our version of `isalpha()` that uses UTF-32 code points:

```
bool isalpha(uint32_t c) {
    return (c >= 0x0041 && c <= 0x005A)
        || (c >= 0x0061 && c <= 0x007A);
}
```

Then we can use the `utf8::iterator` adaptor to adapt the `basic_string::iterator` from octets into UTF-32 code points:

```
#include <utf8.h>

bool contains_non_alpha
    = std::find_if(utf8::iterator(name.begin(), name.begin(), name.end()),
                   utf8::iterator(name.end(), name.begin(), name.end()),
                   [](uint32_t c) { return !isalpha(c); }) != name.end();
```

For slightly better performance at the cost of safety, you can use `utf8::unchecked::iterator`:

```
#include <utf8.h>

bool contains_non_alpha
    = std::find_if(utf8::unchecked::iterator(name.begin()),
                   utf8::unchecked::iterator(name.end()),
                   [](uint32_t c) { return !isalpha(c); }) != name.end();
```

This will fail on some invalid input.

Using UTF8-CPP in this way assumes that the host encoding is UTF-8, or a compatible encoding such as ASCII. In theory this is still an imperfect solution, but in practice it will work on the vast majority of platforms.

I hope this answer is finally complete!

Comment: +1 I'm not sure if this approach would work in an i18n environment with non-english unicode in wchars, etc, but great response. :)

Comment: name.find_first_not_of returns position or npos (-1). This means the result, when casted to bool will always be true. You need to test against npos for this to make sense.

Comment: @kisplit: Thanks for catching that. Just an oversight on my part.

Comment: @AlexReece: You could use the `utf8::iterator` adaptor from [UTF8-CPP](http://utfcpp.sourceforge.net/) to adapt the `basic_string::iterator` to return code points rather than raw octets, but you’d need an overload of `isalpha` that supports `uint32_t` or `char32_t`. I dunno if C++11 adds anything to `<cctype>` in that regard.

Comment: Re: Unicode You would consider that COMBINING diacritics are letters, right?

Comment: @curiousguy: By themselves? No. After a code point with which they can legally combine? Sure. But then you’re getting into territory that would be best covered by ICU, and this is already an absurdly detailed answer to a simple question.

Comment: Then you are not treating NFC and NFD the same? What a shame! Great answer anyway.

Comment: You can even replace `std::find_if() != end` by `std::any_of`

Comment: this should have been the accepted answer, it covers many different solutions, and also shows you how much C++ has evolved over the years.

Answer (score 5):

If you use Boost, you can use [boost::algorithm::is_alpha](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost/algorithm/is_alpha.html) predicate to perform this check. Here is how to use it:

```
const char* text = "hello world";
bool isAlpha = all( text1, is_alpha() );
```

**Update**:
As the documentation states, "all() checks all elements of a container to satisfy a condition specified by a predicate". The call to all() is needed here, since is_alpha() actually operates on characters.

Hope, I helped.

Comment: You probably meant `const char *test`

Comment: You may want to show what you call fully qualified `all` and `is_alpha` by themselves won't work unless you have the correct `use namespace` which is generally not recommended. Also, what is `text1`?

Answer (score 3):

`C++11` approach using [std::all_of](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of):

```
std::all_of(std::begin(name), std::end(name),
    [](char c){ return std::isalpha(c); });
```

[std::all_of](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) will only return true if *all of* the elements are true according to the supplied *predicate* function.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest investigating the ctype library:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/locale/ctype/

For example, the function `is` (see [ctype.is](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/locale/ctype/is/)) is a way to check properties on letters in locale sensitive manner:

```
#include <locale>
using namespace std;
bool is_alpha(char c) {
    locale loc;
    bool upper = use_facet< ctype<char> >(loc).is( ctype<char>::alpha, quote[0]);
    return upper;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  for (string::iterator it=name.begin(); it!=name.end(); ++it)
  {
    if ((*it) < 0x61 || (*it) > 0x71) 
      // string contains characters other than a-z
  }
```

Comment: the hex count is wrong. please update it with correct HEX codes ( refer asciitable.com ). Also, you can case for 'A'-'Z' as well.

Comment: Avoid magic number ans use `'A'` and `'Z'`, but note that this condition is false for system as [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC).