# To print characters, number and special characters one by one in c++

Tags: c++

I want to print characters, numbers, and special characters one by one below each other, but having an error in taking string.

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<string.h>

main()
{
   string s = "124#$&afhj";
   int i;
   for(i=0;i<s.length();i++)
   {
      if((s[i]>=65&&91>=s[i])||(s[i]>=95&&123>=s[i]))
      {
         cout<<s[i]<<endl;
      }
      else
      {
        if(s[i]>=0&&s[i]<=9)
        {
            cout<<s[i]<<endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<s[i];
        }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Which characters don't you want to print?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88541/how-to-write-code-in-a-question-or-answer

Answer (score 2):

- You are using a non-standard header `<iostream.h>`. It must be `<iostream>`. You aren't using an ancient compiler from the 1990s, are you? There are excellent free and modern C++ compilers available for Windows and Linux. Download one and use it.
- `<string.h>` exists but is not the correct header to get `std::string`; it instead contains C-style `char*` functions and is not what you want here.
- `main` must return `int`, even though a `return 0` statement is not necessary.
- You cannot use `string`, `cout` or `endl` without the `std::` prefix. So make it `std::string`, `std::cout` and `std::endl`. [Do not use `using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).
- [Do not use `std::endl` but `'\n'`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311058/n-or-n-or-stdendl-to-stdcout)
- C++ does not guarantee ASCII, and it does not even guarantee that letters are consecutive (it does guarantee that for digits, see below). While it's unlikely for you to encounter a system which is not ASCII-compatible, you should still get into the habit of writing safe, portable code. Which means that you should not use magic numbers like 65 but use `'A'` instead. And of course, your `>=` comparisons are not guaranteed to work. Getting this right is surprisingly difficult in C++. You can use [`std::isalpha`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha) but must pay attention not to invoke undefined behaviour. See also a [more detailed treatise on this subject](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7616973/3313064).
- 91 is ASCII for ']'. You certainly meant 90 for 'Z'. 95 and 123 are likewise off. Have a look at http://www.asciitable.com/. But, see above, do not use the magic numbers and do not use `>=` comparisons.
- Your code could use more spaces to make it more readable.
- Why declare `i` outside of the loop? It needlessly increases its scope. And it has the wrong type; it's a signed int when it should be an unsigned one, or simply `std::string::size_type`. However, you should consider using a range-based for loop to iterate through the string anyway.
- Testing a character for 0 and 9 does not make sense. You want to test for `'0'` and `'9'`. Note how in this case, C++ does guarantee consecutive values for the characters even if ASCII is not guaranteed. You can therefore use range comparisons safely.

Here we go:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

int main()
{
   std::string s = "124#$&afhj";
   for (auto&& character : s)
   {
      if (std::isalpha(static_cast<unsigned char>(character)))
      {
         std::cout << character << '\n';
      }
      else
      {
        if (character >= '0' && character <= '9')
        {
            std::cout << character << '\n';
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << character;
        }
      }
   }
}
```

This will work. I don't think it's really useful, because what it does is:

- Print digits and letters with a linebreak.
- Print everything else without a linebreak.

But after all, that's what the original program's intention was.

Answer (score -1):

In your code is many mistakes. In my opinion your code should look like:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s = "124#$&afhj";
    unsigned int i;
    for (i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if ((s[i] >= 65 && 91 >= s[i]) || (s[i] >= 95 && 123 >= s[i])) {
            cout << s[i] << endl;
        } else {
            if (s[i] >= 0 && s[i] <= 9) {
                cout << s[i] << endl;
            } else {
                cout << s[i];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is **not portable**, because 65, 91, 95 and 123 could mean anything in C++, and it teaches a bad habit (`using namespace std`), too.