# How to only accept character on c++

Tags: c++

In my program, when the user is prompted for an employee's name, the system prompts him to re-enter his name if he enters a number or only a space. How do I put a requirement decision in parentheses in a while loop, here's my code.

```
std::string NAME;
std::cout << "Please enter the name: " << std::endl;
  std::cin >> NAME;
  while (NAME.length() == 0) {
    std::cout << "Your input is not correct. Please re-enter your name" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> NAME;
  }
```

I'm only going to restrict the input to not being empty, but I don't know how to get the user to only allow characters to enter.

Thank you all.

Comment: simply search for characters which are not allowed, if you find one or more, raise the error message.

Comment: Consider using a RegEx expression to compare the input to valid patterns.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to test a string for letters only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7616867/how-to-test-a-string-for-letters-only)

Comment: Related: https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: @moooeeeep No, I do not want to use a function here.

Comment: Maybe you should clarify what you are actually asking about. Right now it is not really clear whether you are asking about the validation or the loop. Also, you should totally implement this as one or multiple functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::all_of` on the string defined in `algorithm` header file. It should be used with appropriate predicate (`isalpha` for your case defined in `cctype` header file). Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>


int main()
{
    std::string NAME;
    std::cout << "Please enter the name: " << std::endl;

    while (std::getline(std::cin, NAME)) {
        if (NAME.length() == 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Your input is not correct. Please re-enter your name" << std::endl;
        }

        // This will check if the NAME contains only characters.
        else if (std::all_of(NAME.begin(), NAME.end(), isalpha))
        {
            break;
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "Only characters are allowed:" << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Every character has an ASCII code. Use an if condition to check if an input character falls between the ASCII codes for the English alphabets. [ASCII Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSlAA.png). You can convert a character to its ASCII code by simply type-casting it as an integer.

**Example:** *For a character array "ARR", having data: "apple"; doing the following will give you "97".*

std::cout << (int)ARR[0] << std::endl;

Comment: Thanks for your idea. But it seems cannot use ASCII here. I am failed to try it.

Comment: Just wondering, why can't you ? @XuShuoze

Comment: This sure would work in `C`, but there are more elegant ways to do this in `C++` as the other answer proposed.